# Has anyone used Kofax Capture API for creating a Importer to create a batch in Kofax

Tags: api, kofax

I am trying to use Kofax Capture API and trying to write a custom module which will do a scan.
For this i need to create a batch and then process/scan it.

Is there anyway to process/scan a batch?

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, I don't know if it's possible to do inside a custom module.  When writing a custom module you're typically using the Kofax Capture Optimized Custom Module API (DBLiteOpt.dll).  I know you can create an empty batch with a custom module by using BatchCreate method of the RuntimeSession object:

```
'*** Get your Process Id
pid = m_oLogin.ProcessId '*** Create new batch
Set m_oBatch = m_oRuntimeSession.BatchCreate("SomeBatchClass", "MyBatch", pid)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to import documents into that batch.

You can always just create a stand-alone program that imports a batch. Here's some C# pseudo-code:

```
Kofax.AscentCaptureModule.ImportLogin myLogin ;
Kofax.AscentCaptureModule.Application myApp;

// login first
myLogin = new Kofax.AscentCaptureModule.ImportLogin() ;
myApp = myLogin.Login("myUsername", "myPassword") ;

// create a new batch 
Kofax.AscenCaptureModule.BatchClass myBatchClass =
myApp.BatchClasses["MyBatchClassName"];
Kofax.AscentCaptureModule.Batch = 
myApp.CreateBatch(ref myBatchClass, "TheNameOfMYBatch");

// create a new document and set its form type
Kofax.AscentCaptureModule.Document myDoc ;
Kofax.AscentCaptureModule.Page myPage = null ;
myDoc = myBatch.CreateDocument(null) ;
Kofax.AscentCaptureModule.FormType myFormType = 
myBatch.FormTypes[1] // - just hardcoded a form type here
myDoc.set_FormType(ref myFormType) ;

// add some pages to the doc
Kofax.AscentCaptureModule.Pages myPages = myBatch.ImportFile("SomeFilePath") ;
foreach(Kofax.AscentCaptureModule.Page myPage in myPages)
{
     myPage.MoveToDocument(ref myDoc, null) ;
}

myApp.CloseBatch() ;
```

Comment: UPDATE:  It is definitely possible to create a new batch and import pages into inside a custom module.  You can't do it with just the Optimized Custom Module API though - you'll need to use the Kofax Capture Document Access library (DBLite.dll).

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, use Kofax XML (ACXMLAID) proprietary importer, if you create your own importer, you will **lose** kofax team support and assistance.

My company already created an custom exporter and then rollback all projects to Kofax Database Export to get support of Kofax team.

Solving your problem:
***Install ACXMLAID and then save your batches as xml to ACXMLAID import to kofax.***

If you need more details on how to do this, send me a message.

Thank you!