# KoFax Automation with VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, automation, kofax

I've seen this [Has anyone used Kofax Capture API for creating a Importer to create a batch in Kofax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027966/has-anyone-used-kofax-capture-api), but it didn't work out for me.

I'm trying to automate creating a batch and maybe validating a batch from vba(ideally vb.net after).

Is there any sample code to assist me in the right direction? Almost everything I searched lead me to a contractor for hire or licensed software.
I tried figuring it out myself through trial and error but I couldn't even connect to a Kofax session.

```
Dim oFax As ACDB.RuntimeSession
Dim oBatch As ACDB.Batch
Dim pax As ACDB.Process
Dim lFax As ACDB.Login

Set lFax = New ACDB.Login
Set oBatch = oFax.BatchCreate("Test", "Test", 0)
MsgBox (oBatch.Name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code that shows how to create batches is installed with Kofax Capture.  You should find it in CaptureSV\Source\Sample Projects\InpScrpt\Simple.

If you decide not to write your own:

- The current Kofax offering in this area is [Kofax Import Connector](http://www.kofax.com/support/products/import-connectors/kofax-import-connector/2.3/documentation.php).
- KIC product replaces previous separate products "Kofax Import Connector - Folder" and "Kofax Import Connector - XML" (AKA XML Auto Import).  However, even though it is deprecated as of KC 10.1, XML Auto Import is still included with KC for free (run "ACXMLAI.EXE -GUI" to open).  Starting something new with a deprecated product is not a great idea, but it's there and it's free.
- As Brandon mentions in a comment, Kofax partners have products that might suit your needs.

Validation script is a whole different area.  In Kofax Capture Administration, right-click on your document class and choose Document Validation Script which will allow you to create a validation script in VB.NET or SBL (deprecated).

Comment: I ultimately created a program that created an XML import file that would be saved into the C:\ACXMLAID folder. I found too that you could enter validation data through the indexfields. So it nearly validates itself. Just have to enter though each document. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad you found a solution that works for you!  Since it is technically deprecated, just make sure that you test carefully any time you upgrade to a newer version.